# How to negate whole regex

Tags: c#, .net

I have a pattern (pattern) and I want to exclude this characters in string 'test' and find all holes in this expression. Like test, but this characters will be random
For the string 'test' I expect 'test' which is not matched by pattern ()

Comment: Edit your question and reveal what the expected output is.

Comment: Use Regex split or Regex replace with a char not in the input and look at what you have left

Comment: Use a Regex debugging site like regexstorm.net to visualize the matches and what isn't matched..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Regex#Match` here:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(XZ|RP(?!ROD)|R|DP(?!ROD)|D|ST[\d]?|WO)");
Match match = regex.Match("testRPRODRRPWO");

if (!match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("input does not contain pattern");
}
```

Comment: Great, but I want to store all holes